# Is there a callback for notebook exit?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I know that [`$Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24Epilog.html) is called when *Mathematica* is exited; is there a callback upon exiting the notebook? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`NotebookEventActions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NotebookEventActions.html) for this. For example, evaluating

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
    NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> CreateDocument[]}];
```

in your current notebook will open a new one when you close (or try to close) the window.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.